# Rider F# Console Template

Tags: f#, rider

I created F# console project in JetBrains Rider 2018 ide.

Project template identity JetBrains.Common.Console.FSharp
Framework 4.7.1
Project does not build

> .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1.AssemblyAttributes.fs(2, 26): [FS1108]
>   The type 'ValueType' is required here and is unavailable. You must add
>   a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

UPD
I have fix the build by commenting all references in fsproj except FSharp core, and adding refercence to netstandard

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="netstandard" />
    <!--<Reference Include="mscorlib"/>-->
    <!--<Reference Include="System"/>-->
    <!--<Reference Include="System.Core"/>-->
    <!--<Reference Include="System.Numerics"/>-->
    <Reference Include="FSharp.Core">
        <HintPath>..\packages\FSharp.Core.4.3.4\lib\net45\FSharp.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <!--<Reference Include="System.ValueTuple">-->
        <!--<HintPath>..\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.4.0\lib\netstandard1.0\System.ValueTuple.dll</HintPath>-->
    <!--</Reference>-->
</ItemGroup>
```